# Angular getting nested array data

Tags: arrays, angularjs

Hi I have an angular controller

.controller("ordersCtrl", function ($scope, $http, ordersUrl) {

```
$http.get(ordersUrl, )
    .success(function (data) {
        $scope.orders = data;

    })
    .error(function (error) {
        $scope.error = error;
    });
```

I can render a view from the scope data using
{{orders.name}} in Html without issue

However with orders there is an products array nested inside

```
{
approved: true,
email: false,
guardianVoteCount: 50,
name: "The DR 1980s",
products: [
{
count: 1,
id: "d35fa22ee4a6f985",
valuetoday: 120,
edition: "Testing 123",
originalprice: 1,
name: "tested"
}
],
upVoteCount: 1,
username: "The Tester",
id: "385c71634c7c8sde"
},
```

when I try and render the data 
{{orders.products.edition}}   I get nothing back

is there another $scopecontroller function I need to easily access the products nested array within orders ?

Answer (score 0):

`edition` property is part of the first object in products array, so you can get it by

```
{{orders.products[0].edition}}
```

If you're using `ng-repeat` to display your products you can do

```
<div ng-repeat="product in orders.products">
  {{product.edition}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could easily do this

```
$scope.orders = data[0].products

<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="order in orders">
         {{order.edition}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

Since `products` is an array, you need to iterate over it:

```html
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="product in orders.products">
        {{product.edition}}
    </li>
</ul>
```